# Kotlin: No adapter attached; skipping layout :RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement Recyclerview in my kotlin code....
And I'm using Retrofit getting data from webservice and plot it into recycler view

**MainActivity.class**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

internal lateinit var jsonApi:MyAPI
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_drivers)

    // init API
    val retrofitt = RetrofitClient.instance
    if (retrofitt != null) {
        jsonApi = retrofitt.create(MyAPI::class.java)
    }

    //View
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    fetchData()

}

private fun fetchData() {
    compositeDisposable.add(jsonApi.drivers
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe{drivers->displayData(drivers)}
    )
}

private fun displayData(drivers: List<Driver>?) {
    val adapter = DriverAdapter(this,drivers!!)
    recycler_drivers.adapter = adapter
}
```

}

**Adapter.class**

```
class DriverAdapter(internal  var contex:Context, internal var driverList:List<Driver>): RecyclerView.Adapter<DriverViewHolder>()
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DriverViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.driver_layout, parent, false)
        return DriverViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return driverList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DriverViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txt_driver_number.text = driverList[position].driver_number
        holder.txt_first_name.text = driverList[position].first_name
        holder.txt_ph_number.text = driverList[position].ph_number.toString()

    }
}
```

**ViewHolder.class**

```
class DriverViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val txt_driver_number = itemView.txt_driver_number
    val txt_first_name = itemView.txt_first_name
    val txt_ph_number = itemView.txt_ph_number
}
```

This is the **API interface**

```
interface MyAPI {
    @get:GET("data")
    val drivers:Observable<List<Driver>>
}
```

**RetrofitClient Object**

```
object RetrofitClient {
    private var ourInstance : Retrofit? = null

    var instance: Retrofit? = null
        get(){
            if(ourInstance == null){
                ourInstance = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://localhost/BSProject/public/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }
            return ourInstance!!
        }
}
```

and this is the **Model class** which is basically the data coming form my localhost server

```
   class Driver {
        var driver_number: String = ""
        var first_name: String = ""
        var ph_number: Int = 0
    }
```

As you can see I have attached an adapter for Recycleview. so why do I keep getting this error?

I have read other questions related to same problem, but none helps.

Comment: You probably aren't reaching `.subscribe()` where you actually attach your adapter, can you log something there to make sure you're reaching it?

Comment: Can you try to attach layout manager after adding adapter?

Comment: @Rafa it doesn't reach `subscribe()`, what do you think i missed pal?

Comment: @Rafa do i need to share more content... like `RetrofitClient`

Comment: yes, please do that

Comment: @Rafa I have updatd the question pal

Comment: I think I know, what's wrong. You might not be correctly deserializing the response, and your observable might be returning an `onError` but you aren't catching it. Could you pass in the `onError` lambda into your `subscribe` and print the error?

Comment: @Rafa it saying `Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: You get the `No adapter attached` message when the `RecyclerView` gets laid out before an Adapter has been set.It happens because that Retrofit call is asynchronous, and it won't complete before the first layout. Create an empty adapter in the onCreate method, and update the adapter when the async call is completed.

Comment: so, can you please post answer, showing me this please, im kinda android rookie, thanks man

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti in this case the asynchronous nature doesn't actually affect the layout though does it? The recyclerView is laid out before the the asynchronous call is made. The issue is that there is no call to set the adapter because that would happen on a successful response from the api. Which is not happening.

Comment: @Lafoune set the call to the adapter i.e. `recyclerView.adapter = adapter` in your onError and pass in an empty list into the adapter so that it compiles. Since you do set the adapter in this case, I believe the message you are getting will go away. You will still have no data however because you aren't receiving any data in either case.

Comment: @Rafa Check the RecyclerView.dispatchLayout() method. If the async call finishes (successfully or not) after the dispatchLayour method you will have this error message. You have to set an empty adapter.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti you're right. In that case @Lafoune, you could either set up your entire recyclerview as a result of having called the fetched Data, or set your adapter inside of `onCreate()` and as a result of having fetched the data, update the `driverList` in your adapter like Gabriele suggested

Answer (score 2):

Either build the recyclerView inside your `displayData()`

```
private fun displayData(drivers: MutableList<Driver>?) {
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val adapter = DriverAdapter(this,drivers!!)
    recycler_drivers.adapter = adapter
}
```

Or do what Gabriele Suggested where you attach your adapter to the recyclerviewin `onCreate()` and add your response data to your adapter after having made the call. This is the ideal approach

```
class MainActivity: {
   lateinit var driverAdapter: DriverAdapter

    protected void onCreate() {
       ...
       recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_drivers)
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
       recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
       val adapter = DriverAdapter(this)
       recycler_drivers.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun displayData(drivers: List<Driver>?) {
        driverAdapter.setDrivers(drivers)
    }
```

And you'd expose a method in your adapter to set the data `setDrivers()`

```
class DriverAdapter(internal  var contex:Context): 
RecyclerView.Adapter<DriverViewHolder>()
{
    val drivers = mutableListOf()
    ...

    fun setDrivers(drivers: MutableList<Driver>) {
        this.drivers = drivers
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

This will get rid of your `No adapter attached; skipping layout :RecyclerView` error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing this issue because of the asynchronous nature of querying the web service through retrofit.  You don't actually assign the `RecyclerView.Adapter` until after `onCreate` exits.

Try changing the visiblility of the RecyclerView to `Gone` until the adapter is applied in `displayData`, then set it to `Visible`

Comment: I don't think this would matter. The adapter doesn't need to be set in onCreate().